# Is it possible to display fragment in dynamically added viewgroup?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to create a plug & play view. Kind of success full in that but facing difficulty in dealing with a special case: Displaying fragment in dynamically added ViewGroup.

**Problem Step:**

1. User created an Activity
2. User passes the activity instance to our CustomPlugin
3. CustomPlugin creates CustomPluginViewGroup (having ImageView and Fragment)
4. CustomPlugin then adds CustomPluginViewGroup to the given Activity

**Result**

In the dynamically added ViewGroup, ImageView is displayed but fragment is not displaying. No error is thrown.

**Reference Code:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomViewManager customViewManager = new CustomViewManager(this);
    }
}
```

**CustomViewManager.java**

```
public class CustomViewManager {

private CustomViewGroup customViewGroup;

public CustomViewManager(AppCompatActivity context) {
        this.context = context;

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        customViewGroup =(CustomViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view_layout, null);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams dummyParams = new       FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        context.addContentView(customViewGroup, dummyParams);
   }
}
```

**CustomViewGroup.java** - contains the logic of adding the ImageView and Dynamically added Fragments.

**Note:**

1. We don't have access to the ID of the On going Activity Root Layout.
2. If we are forcing user to add the CustomViewGroup in their activity_main.xml file then Fragments are displayed properly.

Whether it is possible to display the fragments in the dynamically added ViewGroup or is their any such restriction in the Android?

Comment: If you can't find an answer, maybe the usage of `android.R.id.content` (delivers you the root view of your activity) will help you.

Comment: Sorry, we don't have access to it. Its a library. We are trying to less dependent on the end programmer. If there is no solution, then we may need to force user either to provide the ID of RootView or we have to enforce user to add CustomViewGroup in their activity. But we are keeping that as last option.